# Adding products ID from client to server with angular

Tags: angular

i want to add products ID to user bag.

I got all the product ID's in the component -

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._subscriptions.push(
      this.route.data.subscribe((data: Data) => {
        const products = data['products'] as IProductInterface[];
        
        this._products = products.map((product) => new Product(product));
    }));
  }
```

Build a function that gets the products to the server -

```
public addProductsToBag(productsId: string[]) {
    this.userSrevice.addProductsToBag(productsId);
  }
```

I want to add the product ID by clicking a button -

`<button class="productButton">Add to bag</button>`

how can i get the ID to pass in the `addProductsToBag` function when I'm clicking the button. thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know about your usecase.you can iterate the products in the HTML and sent the id in the functin.

Example:`<div *ngFor="let item of products;"><button class="productButton" (click)="addToProduct(item.id)">Add to bag</button></div>`

In the ts File,we can use the function
`addToProduct(id:string):void{this.userSrevice.addProductsToBag(productsId);}`